# Why won’t ssh-add -K save my passphrase in the keychain?

Tags: keychain, ssh

I have not been able to save my ssh passphrase to the keychain since upgrading to MacOS Sierra. I understand how to use the `ssh-add -K` flag and the `UseKeychain` configuration option, and my coworkers use them without any problems. My `.ssh/config` contains this:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
```

However, I cannot seem to save the passphrase to keychain, even if I explicitly use `ssh-add -K`! The agent *always* asks for a passphrase when it’s empty, and `ssh-add -A` does not add any keys. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have had this same problem with every single MacOS installation after Sierra. I don't understand what it might be that is messing this up. No amount of googling turns up anything besides "ssh-add -K". :(